# std::unordered_map::emplace behavior with no move/copy constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, unordered-map

I am trying to gain a better understanding of std::unordered_map::emplace, and I think I understand how copy and move constructors are being utilized if they exist. I have outlined the relevant descriptions for each different usages below. If anyone finds any issues with the descriptions, please let me know.

However, what I am mostly curious about is that, what happens when ONLY the default and user-defined constructors are defined? It looks like the default constructor is not called at all, and the user-defined constructor is only called ONCE, so how is it populating the FooBar member of the newly constructed element in the unordered_map? (I'd imagine the default/user-defined constructor to be called at least twice). Also, if FooBar doesn't define copy and move constructors, are there any behavioral differences for the 3 cases below?

Note: I understand that this is a trivial example where deep copies aren't an issue, so copy/move semantics doesn't really yield any significant gain. I am just using this simplified example to get my point across.

```
struct FooBar
{
    FooBar()
    {
        printf("Foobar default constructor called\n");
    };

    FooBar(int* pFoo, int* pBar)
    {
        m_pFoo = pFoo;
        m_pBar = pBar;
        printf("Foobar user-defined constructor called\n");
    };

    FooBar(FooBar & rhs)
    {
        m_pBar = rhs.m_pBar;
        m_pFoo = rhs.m_pFoo;
        printf("Foobar copy constructor called\n");
    };

    FooBar(FooBar && rhs)
    {
        m_pBar = rhs.m_pBar;
        m_pFoo = rhs.m_pFoo;
        rhs.m_pBar = nullptr;
        rhs.m_pFoo = nullptr;
        printf("Foobar move constructor called\n");
    };

    int* m_pFoo;
    int* m_pBar;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::unordered_map<int, FooBar> map;

    //template< class... Args >
    //std::pair<iterator, bool> emplace(Args&&... args);

    // 1. 
    // Description: A lvalue of foobar1 is temporarily created, initialized, copied (via copy constructor)
    // to supply the in-place constructed element's FooBar member, and destroyed
    // Output (if both copy and move constructor exist): Foobar user-defined constructor called, Foobar copy constructor called
    // Output (if both copy and move constructor don't exist): Foobar user-defined constructor called
    {
        FooBar foobar1 = {(int*)0xDEADBEEF, (int*)0x01010101};
        map.emplace(10, foobar1);
    }

    // 2. 
    // Description: A rvalue of bar1 is temporarily created, initialized, moved (via move constructor)
    // to supply the in-place constructed element's FooBar member, and destroyed
    // Output (if both copy and move constructor exist): Foobar user-defined constructor called, Foobar move constructor called
    // Output (if both copy and move constructor don't exist): Foobar user-defined constructor called
    map.emplace(20, FooBar{(int*)0xDEADBEEF,(int*)0x01010101});

    // 3. 
    // Description: A lvalue of foobar1 is temporarily created and initialized. It is then
    // explicitly converted to a rvalue (via std::move), moved (via move constructor) to supply 
    // the in-place constructed element's FooBar member, and destroyed
    // Output (if both copy and move constructor exist): Foobar user-defined constructor called, Foobar move constructor called
    // Output (if both copy and move constructor don't exist): Foobar user-defined constructor called
    {
        FooBar foobar2 = {(int*)0xDEADBEEF, (int*)0x01010101};
        map.emplace(30, std::move(foobar2));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `FooBar(int* pFoo, int* pBar)` is *not* a "default" constructor.

Comment: Are you suggesting the default constructor is called instead of `FooBar(int* pFoo, int* pBar)` when the newly-constructed element in the map is created? If so, how do I override that constructor to see the message? I tried just `FooBar()` and that didn't get called too.

Comment: No I merely suggest that your question is not written accurately, as what you call a "default constructor" is not.

Comment: Ok, I will update the terminology to be more accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have some misunderstanding about basic terminology. A *default constructor* is one that can be called with no arguments. `FooBar(int* pFoo, int* pBar)` is not a default constructor.

Moreover, to get your code to compile on gcc and clang, I had to modify your copy-constructor to `FooBar(FooBar const& rhs)`.

Now, when you say in the comments that *copy/move constructor do not exist*, I suspect you're simply removing their definitions. But this does not mean they won't exist, the compiler will implicitly define one for you (note that VS2013 will not implicitly define a move constructor since it's missing that feature).

When you call `unordered_map::emplace`, the arguments are forwarded to construct a `unordered_map::value_type` object, i.e. a `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, so the calls to `emplace` end up calling an [`std::pair` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

In case 1, you've created an object named `foobar1`, and the call to `emplace` calls 
the `FooBar` copy constructor.

In case 2, the temporary `FooBar` object you've created will be moved, i.e. the `FooBar` move constructor is called, assuming one exists. If it doesn't, the copy constructor will be called.

Case 3 is the same as case 2 because by calling `std::move` you're allowing the move constructor to be invoked, and for the `foobar2` object to be moved.

---

If you do not want the copy/move constructors to be used when emplacing an object into the map, then use the piecewise construction constructor of `std::pair`.

```
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(40),
            std::forward_as_tuple((int*)0xDEADBEEF, (int*)0x01010101));
```

This should print a single line

```
Foobar default constructor called
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43f65147b03ac119)

Comment: It's not really a misunderstanding. I had a default constructor, but I modified it to take arguments without changing its naming. My bad. I have fixed that.

So basically the short answer is, move/copy constructors are defined by the compiler for you. And it looks like your description of 1, 2 and 3 matches that of my comments too. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @lancery You're welcome, I added an example of how to emplace an object without calling the copy/move constructors.